# Bootstrap .tab('show') also expands Group Button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone tell me why the following JavaScript code would expand a Bootstrap button group inside a Bootstrap Tab Container when executed:

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#' + url.split('#')[1] + ']').tab('show');
}
```

The HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="tabs-color-profile">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#myProfile">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#partner">Partner</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dependants">Dependants</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dependants">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Dependants</h3>

                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <div class="btn-group open">
                            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                Add Dependant
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">My Dependant</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Partner's Dependant</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Additional tabs HTML has been omitted to clean it up a bit.

Note: I'm using the JS to automatically load the correct tab based on the name in the location hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Change

```
<div class="btn-group open">
```

To

```
<div class="btn-group">
```

Comment: Wow! What a complete idiot. Thanks for that, it works perfectly. Out of interest why would it not affect that group button if there was no code there? I.e. I always had the open class there, but it never expanded by default... perhaps it was just that it was hidden? 
Thanks again, appreciate it.